# Obtaining multiple output in regression using deep learning

Tags: deep-learning, regression

Given an RGB image of hand and 3d position of the keypoints of the hand as dataset, I want to do this as regression problem in DL. In this case input will be the RGB image, and output should be estimated 3d position of keypoints.
I have seen some info about regression but most of them are trying to estimate one single value. Is it possible to estimate multiple values(or output) all at once?

For now I have referred to this [code](http://cookie-box.hatenablog.com/entry/2017/08/15/001805). This guy is trying to estimate the age of a person in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output vector from a neural net can represent anything as long as you define loss function well. Say you want to detect (x,y,z) co-ordinates of 10 keypoints, then just have 30 element long output vector say (x1,y1,z1,x2,y2,z2..............,x10,y10,z10), where xi,yi,zi denote coordinates of ith keypoint,  basically you can use any order you feel convenient with. Just be careful with your loss function. Say you want to calculate RMSE loss, you would have to extract tripes correctly and then calculate RMSE loss for each keypoint, or if you are fimiliar with linear algebra, just reshape it into a 3x10 matrix correctly and and have your results also as a 3x10 matrix and then just use

```
loss = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(Y1, Y2)))
```

But once you have formulated your net you will have to stick to it.

Comment: thanks a lot! your comment and [this](https://qiita.com/cvusk/items/1439c1c6dde160c48d13) solved my problem.